# money representation in R

Tags: r, currency

I would like to know how can I work with money with R. It means, do arithmetic, print well formatted numbers and etc.

For example I have some values

```
1.222.333,37 
1.223.444,88
```

I could translate it to numeric and round it, removing the cents, but there isn't a better pattern to work with? I did try the format method, something like:

```
format(141103177058,digits=3,small.interval=3,decimal.mark='.',small.mark=',')
```

but without success. any tip or ideas?

Comment: Formatting of output should always be left until output, you can always write your own function to print in the way you want, but what is your question?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "work with money"?

Comment: i did update my question

Comment: See also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7147706/269476

Comment: thanks @James for output it is great, but i would like as well to handle the numbers keeping the cents, run apply over the vectors, etc

Comment: Floating-point is not a good representation for currency, for which you usually want accurate values to the cent (or better).  `0.01` cannot be exactly represented in base-2 floating point.  Fixed-point representation is usually used instead.

Answer (score 9):

The scales package has a function for this:
[dollar_format()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/scales/versions/0.4.1/topics/dollar_format)

```
install.packages("scales")
library(scales)

muchoBucks <- 15558.5985121
dollar_format()(muchoBucks)

[1] "$15,558.60"
```

Answer (score 5):

Suppose we have two specific character values (currency):

```
s1 <- "1.222.333,37"
s2 <- "1.223.444,88"
```

First of all we want R to display numeric values with proper number of digits:

```
# controls representation of numeric values
options(digits=10)
```

Converting currency to numeric can be implemented like this:

```
# where s is character
moneyToDouble <- function(s){
  as.double(gsub("[,]", ".", gsub("[.]", "", s)))
}

x <- moneyToDouble(s1) + moneyToDouble(s2)
x
```

Printing numeric as currency:

```
# where x is numeric
printMoney <- function(x){
  format(x, digits=10, nsmall=2, decimal.mark=",", big.mark=".")
}

printMoney(x)
```

Comment: `printMoney(100000)` prints `"1e+05"`

Comment: @user443854 Maybe format(scientific = FALSE) would have solved that problem.

Answer (score 5):

What about this one:

```
printCurrency <- function(value, currency.sym="$", digits=2, sep=",", decimal=".") {
  paste(
        currency.sym,
        formatC(value, format = "f", big.mark = sep, digits=digits, decimal.mark=decimal),
        sep=""
  )
}

printCurrency(123123.334)
```

Comment: This works so well! Thanks!!