# Formatting values in knitr output

Tags: r, knitr

My script runs in RStudo and the output shows up in the console window with the number formatted like this: 13367566000

However when I run KnitHTML the numbers are formatted like this: 1.337e+10

How do I set formatting for knitr output so that I can get the result formatted as a dollar amount? (eg, $13,367,566,000).  If this isn't simple, I would at least like it expanded like it printed out in RStudio

Thank you

Comment: what does "formatted as a dollar amount" mean?

Comment: good question.  I edited the question to clarify.  ty

Comment: does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028995/money-representation-in-r. Alternatively, you could define a class to print how you want, for example: `print.dolladollabillsyall <- function(x) print(sprintf('$%s.00', x)); (x <- 11); class(x) <- 'dolladollabillsyall'; x`

Answer (score 2):

You can try my package [formattable](https://github.com/renkun-ken/formattable) which has a built-in function `currency` to make a `formattable` object as a wrapper of numeric vector.

```
> # devtools::install_github("renkun-ken/formattable")
> library(formattable)
> currency(c(123456,2345,12345))
[1] $123,456.00 $2,345.00   $12,345.00
```

The currency symbol can be changed:

```
> currency(c(123456,2345,12345), "HK$")
[1] HK$123,456.00 HK$2,345.00   HK$12,345.00
```