# Formatting all columns using mutate_all in dplyr

Tags: r, string, formatting, dplyr

I'm looking at formatting a table using [**`scales::dollar`**](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/scales/versions/0.4.1/topics/dollar_format) ***within*** `mutate_all`.

## Desired results

The desired results can be obtained with use of the `sapply`:

```
>> sapply(mtcars, scales::dollar)
      mpg      cyl  disp      hp     drat    wt      qsec     vs   am   gear carb
 [1,] "$21.00" "$6" "$160.00" "$110" "$3.90" "$2.62" "$16.46" "$0" "$1" "$4" "$4"
 [2,] "$21.00" "$6" "$160.00" "$110" "$3.90" "$2.88" "$17.02" "$0" "$1" "$4" "$4"
 [3,] "$22.80" "$4" "$108.00" "$93"  "$3.85" "$2.32" "$18.61" "$1" "$1" "$4" "$1"
 [4,] "$21.40" "$6" "$258.00" "$110" "$3.08" "$3.22" "$19.44" "$1" "$0" "$3" "$1"
```

## Challenge

Attempt to achieve the same results via `dplyr` pipeline **and** [**`scales::dollar`**](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/scales/versions/0.4.1/topics/dollar_format):

```
mtcars %>% mutate_all(funs(scales::dollar(.)))
```

fails:

```
Error in vapply(dots[missing_names], function(x) make_name(x$expr), character(1)) : 
  values must be length 1,
 but FUN(X[[1]]) result is length 3
```

### Further exploration

A primitive workaround can be attempted:

```
mtcars %>% mutate_each(funs(as.character(paste0("$", .))))
```

*results:*

```
>> mtcars %>% mutate_each(funs(as.character(paste0("$", .))))
     mpg cyl   disp   hp  drat     wt   qsec vs am gear carb
1    $21  $6   $160 $110  $3.9  $2.62 $16.46 $0 $1   $4   $4
2    $21  $6   $160 $110  $3.9 $2.875 $17.02 $0 $1   $4   $4
3  $22.8  $4   $108  $93 $3.85  $2.32 $18.61 $1 $1   $4   $1
```

Following [a similar discussion,](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14028995/1655567) the approach could be easily developed further to create the desired currency format, but this is not the point.

## Question

- Why `scales::dollar(.)` fails when applied within `mutate_all` (or `mutate_each`)? When
  applied to vector elements it works as expected, shouldn't this behaviour be replicated along observations available in a column when passed within `mutate_all` / `mutate_each`:

  ```
  >> scales::dollar(c(1, 1e4)) 
  [1] "$1"      "$10,000"
  ```

Comment: It's deprecated or will be soon: https://blog.rstudio.org/2016/06/27/dplyr-0-5-0/

Comment: @Frank Correct, I checked and amended the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need to wrap with `as.character` as it seems to be a bug when we use `package::function` in the `funs`.  It is documented [here](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/2089)

```
mtcars %>% 
     mutate_each(funs(as.character(scales::dollar(.))))
```

Besides, the function `mutate_each` is getting deprecated based on the blog link @Frank shared, so we can use `mutate_at`

```
mtcars %>% 
       mutate_at(names(.), funs(as.character(scales::dollar(.))))
```

The remedy would be to load the package and then call without the `::`

```
library(scales)
mtcars %>% 
    mutate_at(names(.), funs(dollar(.)))
```

Or

```
mtcars %>% 
        mutate_at(names(.), dollar)
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the comprehensive answer, I've updated the question with reference to `mutate_all`.  Concerning the attributes, `class(scales::dollar(10))` returns `character` and `str` on the same object shows `chr "$10"`; how can I better interrogate the resulting object to avoid similar pitfalls in future?

Comment: @Konrad Seems like a bug.  Updated the post