# Format numbers in charts as percentages

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to format a number as percentage in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145826/how-to-format-a-number-as-percentage-in-r)

This must be a newbie questions, but how do I format numbers in charts (say PerformanceSummary in PerformanceAnalytics) as percentages? The data I use are in the format of 0.04 etc. Everything is working fine, except I want the charts to show percentages.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

Here is how I am doing it now (with standard data for simplicity reasons):

```
library("PerformanceAnalytics")
data(managers)
charts.PerformanceSummary(managers)
```

I put it here while I go googling for providing my own labels.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145826/how-to-format-a-number-as-percentage-in-r

Comment: When running `charts.PerformanceSummary((sprintf(%1.2f%%", 100*funds))` it complains that the data cannot be converted into a time series.

Comment: In general, the answer is to provide your own custom labels to the plot. So the answer depends on which plot system you are using, i.e. base, lattice or ggplot. If you post a reproducible example, you are more likely to get an answer.

Comment: Looking at the source code of the summaryplot you use, makes it pretty obvious you won't be able to do that without rewriting a couple of functions in that package. I found at least one triple nested call to the underlying base plot functions. The most obvious is to multiply your data with 100. The less obvious is rewriting that part of the package.

Comment: I will break it apart into individual charts and use the solution @Andrie provided below.

Answer (score 9):

Unless I miss something, I don't think this is a newbie question at all.

(Disclaimer: I think this answer isn't particularly elegant, and the graphic sucks.  But hopefully it can serve as a template so somebody else can improve and post some proper code.)

Here is one way of doing it in base graphics:

- Set up the plot without the y-axis, i.e. use `yaxt="n"`
- Calculate where you want the labels to be located, e.g. using `seq`
- use `sprintf` and `round` to format the labels as text with percentage sign

Some code:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- runif(10)
plot(x, type="h", yaxt="n")
yLabels <- seq(0.2, 0.8, 0.2)
axis(2, at=yLabels, labels=sprintf(round(100*yLabels), fmt="%2.2f%%"), las=1)
```

The plot:

[image]

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you very much. I will come back and upvote this answer once I have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is 'you cant'.

Take your performance chart. This is a big piece of programming code, written by someone to do a fancy chart and at some point the author decided to label the Y axes with fractional values to show whatever it is - the fraction of managers to fire this month maybe.

If you want to change that to percentages, then somewhere in that code you need to change it to multiply the axis labels by 100, stick a "%" sign on them, and draw them.

You can do that, because R, and that performance charts package, are released under a license that lets you edit their code. Go do it. You'll learn stuff.

Graphical entities have no independent existence like they do in Excel or SPSS - you can't just say "restyle all my fractional axis labels as percentages". It just don't work like that.

Comment: I will report back when I have fixed R.