# Dividing dataframes of unequal sizes

Tags: r, division

I have data(e - 32 obs. of 3 variables) that contains the following columns

```
Month Years Seats    
10    2011  4477    
11    2011  12210    
12    2011  12617    
1     2012  12617    
...and so on, up to    
5     2014  25234
```

Another data (f - 101 obs. of 3 variables) that contains

```
Month Years Seats    
1     2006  27787    
up to    
5     2014  29017
```

My purpose is to divide the number of seats in e by the number of seats in f, if the year and month for both e and f are the same. My effective result would be getting a table that displays the result of division in percentage

```
Month Years Change in Seats    
10    2011  14.72%    
11    2011  42.28%
```

I tried taking -

- a subset of "f" and then compare with "e" to perform division, but failed at doing so
- a merge of (e,f) and then perform division
- running a for loop, but didn't help

  ```
  g<-{
      for(i in 2006:2014)
        {
        for (j in 1:12)
          {
            if(i==e[,2] && i==f[,2] && j==e[,1] && j==f[,1])
              {
                (e[,3]/f[,3])
              }
            else
              {
                'NA'
              }
          }
        }
    }
  g
  ```

Any help on this would be highly appreciated. Just begun working in R a couple of days ago.  Please let me know if you would like any further information to attempt this question.

Answer (score 0):

I think merge will be your best bet.

```
df1 <- data.frame(month = 1:12, year = rep(2011,12), seats = round(runif(12,10000,20000)))
df2 <- data.frame(month = 2:10, year = rep(2011,9), seats = round(runif(9,10000,20000)))

df3 <- merge(df1, df2, by=c("month", "year"))

df3$change <- df3$seats.x/df3$seats.y
```

If you need to display the change as a percent rather than a decimal, check [How to format a number as percentage in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145826/how-to-format-a-number-as-percentage-in-r)