# Retain percentage formatting when passing percentage values to a data frame

Tags: r, formatting

I have programmed a function that yields percentage values. When I pass the values on to a data frame, the formatting is lost; e.g. 99.90% will turn into 0.9990. Some simple code to illustrate this (1st column is to indicate that I don't want percentages in all columns):

```
DT = data.frame(matrix(0,nrow=1,ncol=5), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
DT[1,1]   = 100
DT[1,2:5] = percent(c(0.9999,0.4567,0.3256,0.7777))

DT

X1     X2     X3     X4     X5
1 100 0.9999 0.4567 0.3256 0.7777
```

I noticed that, in order to keep the percentage formatting, I need to format the data frame in advance. However, I can only do so column by column

This works:

```
DT[,2] = percent(DT[,2])
DT[,3] = percent(DT[,3])
...
```

But it is a bit tedious. Unfortunately, both lines below yield the same error

```
DT[,c(2,3,4,5)] = percent(DT[,c(2,3,4,5)])
DT[,2:5] = percent(DT[,2:5])

Error in UseMethod("percent") : 
no applicable method for 'percent' applied to an object of class "data.frame"
```

This also doesn't work:

```
DT[,2:5] = apply(DT[,2:5],MARGIN = 2 ,FUN=percent)
```

I was therefore wondering whether there is:

- **a way to keep the percentage formatting of a value when it is passed on to a data frame when, for the latter, it has not been specified in advance what the formatting is**; or,
- **an efficient way to assign the percentage formatting to a large number of columns of a data frame**.

Comment: Your first code-block yields `100 100.0% 45.7% 32.6% 77.8%` on my system (i.e. it's retaining the percent format). Which `percent()` are you using? I used `scales::percent()`.

Comment: I had edited the post to include `library(scales)` since I supposed that this package is where the `percent()` function comes from. Reading the comment by @hrbrmstr I realize that elsewhere there may be other functions with that name. Please specify the library that you used.

Comment: I was using percent() from formattable. Changing to scales gives the desired result. Thanks!

Comment: With the `scales::percent` function one cannot specify the decimals? With the one from `formattable` one can.

Comment: Sorry for spamming, but is there a way to keep 2 decimals with `scales::percent`?

Comment: Check out Richie Cotton's custom `percent` function in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145826/how-to-format-a-number-as-percentage-in-r. You can specify the number of digits you want with the `digits` parameter in his function.

Comment: Thanks @MikeyMike, the question in the post you referred to also made me realize I can do `percent(round(x,4))` which gives a percentage with two decimals. This question is solved. @hrbrmstr, if you convert your comment to an answer, I'll pick it as the one that provided the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @hrbrmstr pointed out, I have to use `scales::percent()` to make my code work. To obtain two digits I can either `scales::percent(round(x,4))` or `formattable::percent(x, 2)`. Specifyingthe `namespace` (`scales` or `formattable`) allows you to use functions from masked packages.