# Formatting percentages in R-package openxlsx

Tags: r, excel, xlsx, openxlsx

R3.2.3/openxlsx 3.0.0

I have several dataframes that I'm writing to an Excel-workbook with openxlsx. One of the dataframes contains values such as 0.07. With

```
createStyle(numFmt='PERCENTAGE')
```

I get 7.00% as output in the workbook. So far so good. But I want 7% as output. I've tried several things, such as stacking styles,

```
createStyle(numFmt=c('PERCENTAGE','0'))

createStyle(numFmt='PERCENTAGE 0')
```

but they either result in errors or give unwanted results. Any suggestion in the right direction would be most welcome. Upgrading to a newer version of openxlsx is not an option.

Comment: See the `percent` function from `scales` R package. Also check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145826/how-to-format-a-number-as-percentage-in-r)

Comment: If you can, include a short but complete example of your code so far, with example data. Also, a potential "hacky" solution would be to create a second style which sets the number of decimal places to what you want and add that after you've specified it's percentage. I haven't checked that this works, and it would not be efficient, but you're interacting with excel through R so...

Answer (score 23):

You can create a percent style with no decimal places using Excel's formatting codes and then apply the style to specific cells. For example:

```
library(openxlsx)

# Fake data
set.seed(2)
dat = data.frame(v1=LETTERS[1:10], v2=runif(10), v3=letters[1:10], v4=runif(10))

# Create an Excel workbook object and add a worksheet
wb = createWorkbook()
sht = addWorksheet(wb, "Data")

# Create a percent style
pct = createStyle(numFmt="0%")

# Add fake data to the worksheet we just created
writeData(wb, sht, dat)

# Add the percent style to the desired cells
addStyle(wb, sht, style=pct, cols=c(2,4), rows=2:(nrow(dat)+1), gridExpand=TRUE)

saveWorkbook(wb, "my_workbook.xlsx")
```

An advantage of using Excel's percent format is that the underlying data in the spreadsheet will still be numeric, rather than, say, text strings.

Here's what the worksheet looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Extending from @parL's answer. For this approach to work, you need to remove `createStyle(numFmt='PERCENTAGE 0')`:

You can try to do something like this:

```
i<-sapply(df, is.numeric)
df[i]<-lapply(df[i], scales::percent)
```

This makes all numeric value columns in the data frame to string format.