# Include percentage sign in data R

Tags: r, import

I have a dataframe, where some values are just numeric (1,43,912, 0.01), and then some data is percentages. In the .xlsx file they are written as "38%, 1%" and such. I do not need to manipulate the percentage data, but when I read them into R (using read_excel), they are automatically converted to 0.38, eventhough they are still a string. Is there a way to bypass this? That is, make R read it into the data-frame as "38%" and not "0.38" while keeping the other numerics as they are?

Comment: Leave the import as is, and instead format the percentage from inside R, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145826/how-to-format-a-number-as-percentage-in-r

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data frame is df, and you'll need to change all columns where all values are lower then or equal to 1:

```
for(i in 1:dim(df)[2]){
if(class(df[,i])=="numeric"&all(df[,i]<=1)){
df[,i]=sapply(df[,i],function(x)paste0(x,"%",collapse="%"))
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The problem is though that i don't know which columns/rows have a %-sign in the file and which does not, thus I "just" need R to not convert it automatically in the first place

Comment: I changed the answer trying to answer it better. Is that it?

Comment: Well, almost. I might (!) also have some values which are just 0.1, but is not 10%

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that excel only shows it as 38% but the data is saved as 0.38, thus it is impossible (as far as I found out).