# format inline code as percent or with thousand separator

Tags: r-markdown

the text book chapter on [inline formatting](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/markdown-syntax.html#inline-formatting) does not have much on how to format the *results* of inline code as follows in my .rmd:

training set has `r n_[1]` rows and `r n_[2]` columns which is a matrix with `r n_[1] * n_[2]` entries while only `r dim(fulldataset)[1] / (n_[1] * n_[2])` items are rated.

the inline code in above is using a pair of backticks.  This produces the following when knitted:

> training set has 69878 rows and 10677 columns which is a matrix with
>   746087406 entries while only 0.0120630035135588 items are rated.

i'd like # rows & columns to be formatted with comma and the last expression as %.   I do not seem to find any relevant thread on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the answers in this thread to wrap your calculations in your inline code [How to format a number as percentage in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145826/how-to-format-a-number-as-percentage-in-r/41596229)