# How to get percentage on y-axis in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to get the percentage on the y-axis. But some I could not manage to get it.

```
df <- tribble(
  ~id,   ~min,    ~max,
  "1",     5,      40,
  "2",     5,      50,
  "3",     7,      70,
  "4",     8,      90,
  "5",    23,     100,
  "6",    18,      40,
  "7",    34,      50,
  "8",    84,     150,
  "9",    15,      70,
  "10",  100,      90,
)


outs <- cut(df$min, breaks = c(0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100))
library(scales)

table(outs) %>%                                         
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = outs, y = Freq)) + 
  geom_col(col = "black", fill = "steelblue4", alpha = .4) +
  geom_text(
    aes(label = Freq, Freq = Freq + 0.05),
    position = position_dodge(0.9),
    vjust = -0.4) +
  labs(x = "Min", y = "Number of ids") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent)
```

And this is the result:

[image]

I want to have it in both geom_text and the y-axis. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to first calculate the Freq by dividing over the sum of observations.

You can also modify your `geom_text` to get `label = paste0(Freq*100," %")`.
Finally, add some limits to the `scale_y_continuous` to get a y-axis from 0 to 100%

```r
outs = table(outs) / sum(table(outs)) 

outs %>%                                         
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = outs, y = Freq)) + 
  geom_col(col = "black", fill = "steelblue4", alpha = .4) +
  geom_text(
    aes(label = paste0(Freq*100," %"), Freq = Freq + 0.05),
    position = position_dodge(0.9),
    vjust = -0.4) +
  labs(x = "Min", y = "Percentage of ids") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent, limits = c(0,1))
```

[image]

Does it answer your question ?

Comment: Not actually. The y-axis should be from 0 to 100%. For instance, (0,5] should be 20% because of 2/10.

Comment: @zineda, ok sorry I did not get t at the first time. I edited my answer. Does it look better to you ?

Comment: May I ask you how to store both the number of ids and percentage on geom_text?

Comment: You can do it by writing: `geom_text( aes(label = paste0(Freq*10,": ", Freq*100," %"), Freq = Freq + 0.05), position = position_dodge(0.9), vjust = -0.4)`

Comment: One more question. I would like to have only two-digit for the percentage on geom_text. I know that I need to use the sprintf function. But somehow I could not  find the place to put it. Any idea?

Comment: Take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145826/how-to-format-a-number-as-percentage-in-r there is an example of the use of sprintf. In your case, something like `sprintf("%1.2f%%",Freq*100," %"))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203450/discussion-between-zineda-and-dc37).