# Vector representing the percentage of each element

Tags: r

For example I have

```
cw<-c(5,5,10,12,14,16)
```

Where cw is coursework for my course work marks, and the maximum I can get for the coursework assignments is 20. How do I make a new variable, say cwp, which will represent the percentage of each value (out of 20), with the percentage signs?

What I did is

```
cwp<- cw/20
```

But it's giving me the percentage without the "%" sign

Comment: `paste0(round(cw/20,2)*100,"%")`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format a number as percentage in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145826/how-to-format-a-number-as-percentage-in-r)