# how to insert a symbol % in the column in r

Tags: r, data-manipulation

have a data frame like  `mtcars` and i  want to add `%` in the column properly, any help will be appreciated.

```
mtcars1$newcolumn <- paste0(round(mtcars$mpg,digits = 2)*100, collapse = "%")
```

Expected results something like

```
                  mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb new.column
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4    2100%
```

many thanks in advance

Comment: percentage of what yo?

Comment: Just get rid of `collapse = ` in the `paste0` call so the last part is `, "%")`.

Comment: thanks @caldwellst

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a string, just remove the `collapse =`

```
mtcars1$newcolumn <- paste0(round(mtcars$mpg,digits = 2)*100, "%")
```

Or you might want to check out the scales package:
[How to format a number as percentage in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145826/how-to-format-a-number-as-percentage-in-r)

Answer (score 2):

Have a try of `percent` function in `scales` package

```r
scales::percent(21.0,big.mark = "")
#> [1] "2100%"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

An option with `str_c`

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
data(mtcars)
mtcars %>%
    mutate(newcolumn = str_c(round(mpg, 2) * 100, "%"))
```