# round of Percentage based on conditions

Tags: r

Is it possible to round the numbers (remove exponential based on condition). Example

`````
> paste0(as.character(as.numeric(0.00000044854548)), "%")
[1] "4.4854548e-07%"
> paste0(as.character(as.numeric(0.44854548)), "%")
[1] "0.44854548%"
````

expected output (basically stick to 4 non-zero numbers), if it the number is 0.00000044854548, then "0.0000004485%". If the number is 0.44854548, then  "0.4485%"
````
> paste0(as.character(as.numeric(0.00000044854548)), "%")
[1] "0.0000004485%"
> paste0(as.character(as.numeric(0.44854548)), "%")
[1] "0.4485%"
````
`````

Comment: Run `options(scipen = 999)` and try again

Comment: See [How to format a number as percentage in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7145826/4996248)

Answer (score 0):

You may use `formatC`.

```
paste0(formatC(0.00000044854548, format="fg", digits=4), "%")
# [1] "0.0000004485%"
paste0(formatC(0.44854548, format="fg", digits=4), "%")
# [1] "0.4485%"
```