# Trying to understand results of R Scales label_percent()

Tags: r

Any help on understanding the variation on the following results is appreciated!
`> label_percent(accuracy=1:10)(1/3)`
[1] "33%" "34%" "33%" "32%" "35%" "36%" "35%" "32%" "36%" "30%"

I was using some solutions on [How to format a number as percentage in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145826/how-to-format-a-number-as-percentage-in-r/41596229) but found this problem (if so). I'm more curious if I'm doing something wrong than having a solution. I'm using the hand-rolled solution from the link and works well for me. Thanks

Comment: @r2evans thanks for the in-depth answer! I was hoping that an accuracy=2 would give me a label 33.33%. So much to learn!

Answer (score 2):

I think you're mis-using `accuracy=` a little: I think it's intended to be length 1, not length 10. Having length 10 will always return 10 strings for every *single* input. (I've always seen `scales::label_percent` in the lens of axis or text labels on a plot. With that context, my assumption is that for input value passed into the function, there will be exactly one string returned, ergo my "length 1" assumption. There may likely be uses where this is not a necessary constraint.)

Your call is equivalent to

```r
label_percent(accuracy=1)(1/3)
# [1] "33%"
label_percent(accuracy=2)(1/3)
# [1] "34%"
label_percent(accuracy=3)(1/3)
# [1] "33%"
label_percent(accuracy=4)(1/3)
# [1] "32%"
label_percent(accuracy=5)(1/3)
# [1] "35%"
### etc
```

From the docs, `accuracy` is supposed to suggest the number of decimal places:

```
accuracy: A number to round to. Use (e.g.) '0.01' to show 2 decimal
          places of precision. If 'NULL', the default, uses a heuristic
          that should ensure breaks have the minimum number of digits
          needed to show the difference between adjacent values.
```

I'm not sure how I would expect `accuracy=3` (e.g.) to behave in that context.

Ultimately (`label_percent` --> `number_format` --> `number` functions), `accuracy=` is being used within `round_any` and `log10`:

```r
function (x, accuracy = NULL, scale = 1, prefix = "", suffix = "", 
    big.mark = " ", decimal.mark = ".", trim = TRUE, ...) 
{
  # ...
    x <- round_any(x, accuracy/scale)
    nsmall <- -floor(log10(accuracy))
  # ...
}
```

`x` is the number to be formatted, so there is some vector recycling going on here. Since `x` is length 1 and `accuracy` is length 10, then `x` is actually recycled to be the same length. This also happens if `length(x)` goes evenly into `length(accuracy)`, but you start seeing warnings when this is not true:

```r
label_percent(accuracy=1:10)(1/3)
#  [1] "33%" "34%" "33%" "32%" "35%" "36%" "35%" "32%" "36%" "30%"
label_percent(accuracy=1:10)(1:2/3)
#  [1] "33%" "66%" "33%" "68%" "35%" "66%" "35%" "64%" "36%" "70%"
label_percent(accuracy=1:10)(1:3/3)
# Warning in x/accuracy :
#   longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
#  [1] "33%"  "66%"  "99%"  "32%"  "65%"  "102%" "35%"  "64%"  "99%"  "30%"
```

This (to me) indicates that there is not necessarily a solid use-case for multiple `accuracy` values.

Further, the calculation into `nsmall` is passed directly to `format`, which only appears to use the most-permissive value if `nsmall` is a vector:

```r
format(1/3, nsmall=2)
# [1] "0.3333333"
format(1/3, nsmall=2:10)
# [1] "0.3333333"
```

which explains why the number of digits in the output of `label_percent` does not change. (The above is also impacted by `options("digits")`.)

---

If you are intended to control the number of digits, then you need to (1) use an exponential value, and (2) make multiple explicit calls to `label_percent`:

```r
sapply(10^-(1:10), function(acc) label_percent(accuracy=acc)(1/3))
#  [1] "33.3%"          "33.33%"         "33.333%"        "33.3333%"       "33.33333%"     
#  [6] "33.333333%"     "33.3333333%"    "33.33333333%"   "33.333333333%"  "33.3333333333%"
```

You cannot use the exponential trick in a single call to `label_percent` because of the `nsmall[1]` note above:

```r
label_percent(accuracy=10^-(1:10))(1/3)
#  [1] "33.3000000000%" "33.3300000000%" "33.3330000000%" "33.3333000000%" "33.3333300000%"
#  [6] "33.3333330000%" "33.3333333000%" "33.3333333300%" "33.3333333330%" "33.3333333333%"
```