# Format values as percent keeping them numeric

Tags: r, formatting, percentage

I want to format the values as percent, which have % unit also attached to it. I was trying the following steps:

```
df<-data.frame(x=c("A","B","C","D","E"),Y=c(23,24,25,34,32))
df$Z<-sprintf("%.1f%%",df$Y)
```

But in this way the new column z is character. I need to later present a DT table with data bars in the using library(DT). Something like this:

```
datatable(df)%>% formatStyle(c(2:3), background = styleColorBar(c(0,100), 'lightblue'),
                              backgroundSize = '98% 88%',
                              backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat',
                              backgroundPosition = 'center')
```

Since the column Z is now character, bars can not be created on Z.
I am need some solution which can format the numbers to percent (showing % as suffix) but still keeping them as numeric , so that data bars can be created. Data bars can be created on the numeric values only.

Comment: Use two variables: the numeric one to define the values plotted, the character one to label the axes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format a number as percentage in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145826/how-to-format-a-number-as-percentage-in-r)

Comment: @Limey, yes that can be done, thanks

Comment: @tester Formatting a number is not a problem, but it converts the number to character thats a problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use `formatPercentage`

```
df<-data.frame(x=c("A","B","C","D","E"),Y=c(23,24,25,34,32))
df$Z<- df$Y/100

datatable(df) %>%
    formatPercentage(3) %>% 
    formatStyle(3, background = styleColorBar(c(0,1), 'lightblue'),
                         backgroundSize = '98% 88%',
                         backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat',
                         backgroundPosition = 'center')
```

[image]