# How to include percentage and numerator/denominator in the same cell

Tags: r

I am calculating numerators, denominators and percentages and would like these in one cell in R.
How would I do this?

For example, if I have a value of `a = 1` and `b = 2`, if I do`a/b`, I would get 0.5.

What is the best way to express this in the format "50% (1/2)" in a single cell.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format a number as percentage in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145826/how-to-format-a-number-as-percentage-in-r)

Answer (score 1):

`sprintf` is pretty handy for this:

```
sprintf("%0.0f%% (%s/%s)",  a/b *100, a, b)

[1] "50% (1/2)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `glue`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   mutate(perc = glue::glue("({a/b*100}%) {a}/{b}"))
  a b      perc
1 1 2 (50%) 1/2
2 3 4 (75%) 3/4
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(a = c(1, 3), b = c(2, 4)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `dyplr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(perc = paste0("(", a/b*100, "%) ", a, "/", b))
  a b      perc
1 1 2 (50%) 1/2
2 3 4 (75%) 3/4
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  a = c(1,3),
  b = c(2,4)
)
```